# The fastest way to check if multiple substrings occurs at position

Tags: c#, .net, string

There is a function in .NET 
`public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index);`

Is there a simply way to use similar function to find out if substrings occurs at some position (index)?

I mean:

```
public static bool ElementAtPosContains(this string, int index, string[] valuesToCheck)
{ ... }


string test1 = "abcd5f";
string[] substrings = {"1" , "2", "3", "4", "5"};
if (test.ElementAtPosContains(4, substrings))
 {
    DoSomething();
 }
```

If there would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 at 4 position in string - return true. I can do this thing:

```
   public static bool ElementAtPosContains(this string inputStr, int index, string[] valuesToCheck)
   { 
     if (valuesToCheck == null)
       return false;

     foreach (string value in valuesToCheck)
     {
       if (inputStr.Substring(index, value.Length) == value)
         return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
```

But this seems to be not very effective

Comment: If it doesn't have to be done this way, here's an alternative: [`String.IndexOf(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
    public static bool ElementAtPosContains(this string inputStr, int index, string[] valuesToCheck)
    {
        if (valuesToCheck == null || valuesToCheck.Length == 0 || inputStr.Length < index)
            return false;

        return valuesToCheck.Any(sub => string.CompareOrdinal(inputStr, index, sub, 0, sub.Length) == 0);
    }
```

`CompareOrdinal` comparisons are always case-sensitive and don't take culture into consideration. This makes them faster then usual `Compare` or `=` operator. If you don't need culture-aware comparison or case-insensitive comparison, this method should do the job faster since it compares numeric values of characters from the string.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/aOhKym)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be smarter:

```
public static bool ElementAtPosContains(this string inputStr, int index, IList<String> valuesToCheck)
{
    if (valuesToCheck == null || inputStr.Length < index)
        return false;

    return valuesToCheck.Any(s => s.Length + index <= inputStr.Length 
                             &&   inputStr.IndexOf(s, index) == index);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/VKyT4l)

Although i think that you're doing premature optimization.

Comment: Ivan's compare ordinal idea - seems to be faster. Why?

Comment: @BorysławBobulski: How have you measured the time? Btw, his code is open for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` whereas mine handles it.

Comment: I have not. Just click "Demo" and check results

Comment: Btw, his code is open for `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` whereas mine handles it. This costs time. You cannot compare the result from Ideone for several reasons(btw, mine was faster now). You have to create a test yourself using `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: @BorysławBobulski: A quick test revealed that Ivans approach is a little bit faster(without error handling): `Ivan00:00:03.1907295 Tim:00:00:08.6511602` for **10,000,000 iterations**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possibility of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, I fixed it in the demo. Information on why `CompareOrdinal` performs faster can be found at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/string-compare-vs-string-compareordinal-t2429421.html